# WPF Child Window (also WPF) Runs, But Unresponsive

Tags: wpf, vb.net, windows, multithreading, xaml

I checked all 8 matches here, and none of them have this symptom:

I have a spinning world/mouse joystick XAML project running fine in a WPF window-as long as that window is the "Startup URI" in my project's *Properties -> Application -> Statup URI*. It responds to mouse & keyboard as expected.

BUT, when I call that same class from code (menu click, .Show()) as a *child* of a parent WPF window, the child displays fine-and even animates-but is *completely unresponsive* to mouse & keyboard (except to close the window itself.

Now here is the weird part/hint that might tell the right person what the issue is:

When I close the child WPF window by clicking the close("x") widget, the window goes away, but I can see it still generating log entries!

Figuring on a thread-centric need, I have tried the following with no change in symptoms:

A. Just call it:

```
Dim wpfEarth As New vASA.TheEarthWindow
wpfEarth.Show()
```

B. Dispatchers:
(calling function/sub):

```
Dim thread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Me.DisplayEarthOnThread))
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
thread.Start()
thread.Join()
[...]

Private Sub DisplayEarthOnThread()
    Try
        Dim wpfEarth As New vASA.TheEarthWindow
        wpfEarth.Show()
        AddHandler wpfEarth.Closed, Sub(s, e) wpfEarth.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown()
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
    Catch ex As Exception
        [...]
    End Try
End Sub
```

C. A ton of random variations (Me.Dispatcher, MyBase.Dispatcher, ...) on:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub()
    Dim wpfEarth As New vASA.TheEarthWindow
    wpfEarth.Show()
    AddHandler wpfEarth.Closed, Sub(sender2, e2) wpfEarth.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown()
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
        End Sub)
```

D. This is SUPPOSED to kill the child window when it closes, but doesn't (still unresponsive like the above ones):

```
Dim newWindowThread As New Thread(New ThreadStart(Sub()
    ' When the window closes, shut down the dispatcher
    ' Start the Dispatcher Processing
    Dim tempWindow As New TheEarthWindow()
    AddHandler tempWindow.Closed, Sub(s2, e2) Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background)
    tempWindow.Show()
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
        End Sub))
newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
' Make the thread a background thread
newWindowThread.IsBackground = True
' Start the thread
newWindowThread.Start()
```

...
I could really use some insight.

I could always break the project up, which would be clunky. It would be best to understand why/how a responsive child can be launched.